# How do you immediately cancel a firebase storage upload task?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

The problem is that I want to know how to immediately cancel a FirebaseStorage UploadTask.

I have read https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/upload-files but it doesn't have any examples on how to cancel the UploadTask.

```
// Data in memory
var custom_bytes = new byte[] { ... };

// Create a reference to the file you want to upload
Firebase.Storage.StorageReference rivers_ref = storage_ref.Child("images/rivers.jpg");

// Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
rivers_ref.PutBytesAsync(custom_bytes)
  .ContinueWith ((Task<StorageMetadata> task) => {
    if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) {
        Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    } else {
        // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        Firebase.Storage.StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
        string download_url = metadata.DownloadUrl.ToString();
        Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
        Debug.Log("download url = " + download_url);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PutBytesAsync()` method returns a `System.Task<T>` and they natively support cancelation.  I'd suggest reading the [Task Cancellation Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation) as there are some caveats:

> A successful cancellation involves the requesting code calling the
>   [CancellationTokenSource.Cancel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel?view=netframework-4.8) method, and the user delegate
>   terminating the operation in a timely manner. You can terminate the
>   operation by using one of these options:
>
> - By simply returning from the delegate. In many scenarios this is
>     sufficient; however, a task instance that is canceled in this way
>     transitions to the TaskStatus.RanToCompletion state, not to the
>     TaskStatus.Canceled state.
> - By throwing a OperationCanceledException and passing it the token on
>     which cancellation was requested. The preferred way to do this is to
>     use the ThrowIfCancellationRequested method. A task that is canceled
>     in this way transitions to the Canceled state, which the calling code
>     can use to verify that the task responded to its cancellation request.